# Detecting memory leak using boundsChecker

Tags: memory, detection, using, bounds-checker

I am instrumenting my source with boundsChecker for memory detection but when i build it with
native c/c++ instrumentation manager's Error detection type of instrumentation , i am getting 
build errors. when i see the output window it is showing NM2002: Inline expansion (/Ob) used during instrumentation this error ..

but when i select instrumentation type as performance or coverage analysis the source is building successfully but when i run testcases to check memory leaks it is not showing any memory leaks..
can anybody help me on this...
also please suggest me which type of instrumentation should i use to detect memory leaks..

Answer (score 0):

With regards to detecting memory leaks, you need to activate the "Memory Tracking" subsystem.  It is activated by default.  However, it does not track memory allocated by managed C/C++, only by unmanaged.

Would you mind sharing your test case?  I am one of the developers maintaining the product, and if necessary we can arrange for an NDA agreement.

Answer (score 0):

/Obn inlining can really cause errors of instrumented code as we instrument the code in between compile passes. The code is given a first pass of compile and some code might be marked for possible inlining. We then add in all the instrumentation to the intermediate language. The final pass of compile is then made and if they try to inline the code with instrumentation bad things can happen. This is why we disable inlining if possible and generate an error if needed.

Which VS version are you using?
Which version of Devpartner?

You will need to compile with Error Detection to  catch memory leaks. I would suggest a Debug build compile as well with inlining turned off.

Edit I just ran a few tests with VS2008 and VS2010 and the current 11.1 Release candidate

I did not get an error but rather

1>  Instrumentation is adding (/Ob0) to turn off inlining
1>cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/Ob1' with '/Ob0'

Warning 1   warning D9025: overriding '/Ob1' with '/Ob0'    e:\cust\Anthony\Test\Test\cl    Test
Warning 2   warning D9025: overriding '/Ob1' with '/Ob0'    e:\cust\Anthony\Test\Test\cl    Test

These messages tell that we are disabling Inlining. You would only have this as an error if you have treat warnings as errors enabled.